# Checkboxes, Radios, 'select or other' wont render inside table select element

Tags: 7, forms

I want to render elements of type checkboxes or radios inside tableselect, but what I get are empty html tags. Textfield and select type elements render fine.

Basically this renders fine.

```
$tableSelectTesting = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array(
    "1000" => "$1000",
    "other" => t("Other"),
  ),
);
```

This does not.

```
$tableSelectTesting = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
      "1000" => "$1000",
      "other" => t("Other"),
    ),
);
```

I add the form element to table select using the 'data' array key.

```
$options[$index] = array(
    'column1' => $column1Data,
    'column2' => array(
      'data' => $tableSelectTesting,
    )
  );
```

This is the output I get for the radios element.

```
<td><div id="some-id" class="form-radios"></div></td>
```

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing some details in the way you structure your data. Check [this example](https://www.drupal.org/node/945102#drupal7), specifically the data array tree.

Also, check the structure of the array that defines the tableselect. For radios it should look like this:

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#multiple' => FALSE,
);
```

(the #multiple property is the one that defines whether these are checkboxes or radios)

Your data in the array `$options` should look something like this:

```
$options = array(
  '1000' => array(
      'field_price' => '$1000',
  ),
  'other' => array(
      'field_price' => 'Other',
  ),
);
```

Notice the nested structure, and the field name (this could be anything, but it needs to exist, one for every column of the table, starting with the second column.